# Dropdown item in html table is not selecting correct value in row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where the user can select row and they can edit in the header of the table. The problem is that, when they select row and changed the value; for example the Category. When first time edit the row and click the update, it will change accordingly. But when they select another value for Category or any other dropdown. They cannot changed it back from the previous value.

This is my code snippet, don't mind the **background-color**

```
    var opt = $("#Category_h option:selected").val(); 
    $('#' + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Category]').find("#Category option[value='" + opt + "']").attr("selected", true);
    if ($("#" + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Category]').css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
        if (opt != '') {
            $("#" + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Category]').css('background-color', '');
        }
    }
```

Here's my whole code: [Sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/s7q8y1n0/1/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is you are using attr method which selects the options but you have not unselected it hence it stops working. You can use below modified code snippet to make things work.

```
$("input[name='Update']").click(function () {

        if ($(this).attr("data-tr") == "-1") { return; };
        var dataTR = $(this).attr("data-tr");
        dataTR = dataTR.trim();
        var customer_model; 

        var opt = $("#Category_h option:selected").val(); 
        console.log(opt);
        $('#' + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Category]').find("#Category").val(opt);
        if ($("#" + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Category]').css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
            if (opt != '') {
                $("#" + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Category]').css('background-color', '');
            }
        }
        var tax = $("#Tax_rule_h option:selected").val();
        $('#' + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Tax_rule]').find("#Tax_rule").val(tax);
        if ($("#" + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Tax_rule]').css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
            if (tax != '') {
                $("#" + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Tax_rule]').css('background-color', '');
            }
        }
        var term = $("#Payment_term_h option:selected").val();
        $('#' + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Payment_term]').find("#Payment_term").val(term);
        if ($("#" + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Payment_term]').css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
            if (term != '') {
                $("#" + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Payment_term]').css('background-color', '');
            }
        }

        //BTG v.1.0.0.3
        var curr = $("#Currency_h option:selected").val();
        $('#' + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Currency]').find("#Currency").val(curr);
        console.log(curr);
        if ($("#" + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Currency]').css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
            if (curr != '') {
                $("#" + dataTR).find('td[data-attr=Currency]').css('background-color', '');
            }
        } 

    });
```

hope this will help you